# Area of Convex hull

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, area, computational-geometry, triangulation

> For every point set $A \subset R^2$, prove that in general the sum of the coordinates of $\phi(T)$ is independent of a triangulation T and is associated to the area of the Convexv_Hull(A).

We define vector $\phi(T) \subset R^n$, where $n$ is the number of points that we use in the triangulation<sup>*</sup>. Every $i-th$ coordinate of $\phi(T)$ is equal to the sum of areas of the triangles in T that contain $p_i$.

---

That looks pretty straightforward to me (since no matter how we partition the space, the area is a constant value<sup>$</sup>), intuitively, but how to approach its proof?

---

*<sub>we assume that a triangulation uses all points of a point set</sub>

$<sub>As the Cake By The Ocean song says: And no matter how you slice it...it's a piece of cake.</sub>

Comment: Hint: Each triangle is counted how many times in the final sum?

Comment: @Rahul you mean in the sum per coordinate of $\phi(T)$ or in all sums (i.e. in all cordinates) of $\phi(T)$?

Comment: The sum over all coordinates. Of course a triangle is counted at most once in a single coordinate.

Comment: I did an example in $R^2$, with 5 points and the answer is 3 @Rahul. Where are we going with this? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given any triangulation $T$ of $A$, let 
$t_1, t_2, \ldots, t_f$ be the triangles of $T$ 
and $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_f$ be the corresponding area. Define

$$\theta_{ij} = \begin{cases}
1, & p_i \in t_j\\
0, & \text{ otherwise }
\end{cases}
\quad\text{ for }\quad 1 \le i \le n;\; 1 \le j \le f$$
We have 
$\displaystyle\;\phi(T)_i = \sum_{j=1}^f \theta_{ij} a_j\;$
and
$\displaystyle\;\sum_{i=1}^n \theta_{ij}  = 3\;$. As a result,
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \phi(T)_i 
= \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^f \theta_{ij} a_j
= \sum_{j=1}^f \sum_{i=1}^n \theta_{ij} a_j 
= \sum_{j=1}^f 3 a_j
= 3\sum_{j=1}^f a_j
= 3\,\verb/Area/(\textrm{co}(A))$$

Comment: Oh damn it, I should have known from the comment of Rahul! Thanks Mr. eye of ra. :)